# Java SQL application . inputs not updating into my database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am totally new to java, have only started a few weeks ago. I have an assignment that has to be complete soon. The assignment states that i have to create a JAVA application for a book shop that allows a user to perform database operations using an appropriate GUI.

This project must have 3 classes. one for GETTERS AND SETTERS another for the GUI elements and finally one for the SQL DATABASE PREPARED STATEMENTS.

in advance, i apologies for what is probably bad code quality.

My problem seems to be, that when i run the project and try to update or insert or delete , that it never works, instead the JOPtionPane "Data is not saved" pops up instead.

I would really appreciate any help , tips , advise . the code for my project is as follows:

BOOK CLASS ( GETTERS AND SETTERS) :

```
package bookDatabase;


public class Book {
String bookName; // Create Variable for the book name//
String authorName;
String price; 

            //We now create the setters and getters
            public Book( String bookName, String authorName, String price){
                this.bookName = bookName;
                this.authorName = authorName;
                this.price = price;
                }

            public void setbookName (String bookName ){
                this.bookName = bookName;
            }

            public void setauthorName (String authorName){
                this.authorName = authorName;
            }

            public void setprice (String price){
                this.price = price;
            }

            public String getbookName(){
                return bookName;
            }

            public String getauthorName (){
                return authorName;
            }

            public String getprice (){
                return price;
            }



            @Override
            public String toString(){
                return bookName + authorName + price ;  
            }

            }
```

Now the guiBook class:

```
 package bookDatabase;

  import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class guiBook extends JFrame{

private String bookName;
private String authorName;
private String price;
Book b1 = new Book(bookName, authorName, price);
BookQuerie q1 = new BookQuerie(bookName, authorName, price);
private JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
private JTextArea areaShow= new JTextArea("List of All Books");
private JTable selectArea = new JTable();

 private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
private JLabel update1 = new JLabel ("Insert Name of Book", JLabel.LEFT);
private JTextField updateField1 = new JTextField(20);
private JLabel update2 = new JLabel ("Enter the new Price", JLabel.LEFT);
private JTextField updateField2 = new JTextField(20);
private JButton updateButon = new JButton("Update price");


private JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
private JTextField firstInsert = new JTextField(20);
private JTextField secondInsert = new JTextField(20);
private JTextField thirdInsert = new JTextField(20);
private JButton insertButton = new JButton("Insert New Book");
private JLabel labelInsert1 = new JLabel("Enter Book Name", JLabel.LEFT);
private JLabel labelInsert2 = new JLabel("Enter Author Name", JLabel.LEFT);
private JLabel labelInsert3 = new JLabel("Enter Price");

private JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
private JTextField firstDelete = new JTextField(20);
private JButton buttonDelete = new JButton("Delete Book");
private JLabel labelDelete = new JLabel ( "Enter Name of Book", JLabel.LEFT);


public guiBook() throws Exception{
    pane.add("Display All Books", panel1);
    panel1.add(areaShow, BorderLayout.WEST);
    areaShow.setEditable(false);
    panel1.add(selectArea, BorderLayout.EAST);



    {

    pane.add("Update Book Price", panel2);
    panel2.add(update1);
    panel2.add(updateField1);
    panel2.add(update2);
    panel2.add(updateField2);
    panel2.add(updateButon);
    updateButon.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String bookName = updateField1.getText();
        String price = updateField2.getText();
        try {
            BookQuerie.updateBooks(bookName, price);
        }
        catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    });

    pane.add("Insert New Book",panel3);
    panel3.add(labelInsert1);
    panel3.add(firstInsert);
    panel3.add(labelInsert2);
    panel3.add(secondInsert);
    panel3.add(labelInsert3);
    panel3.add(thirdInsert);
    panel3.add(insertButton);
    insertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String bookName = firstInsert.getText();
            String authorName = secondInsert.getText();
            String price = thirdInsert.getText();
            try {
                BookQuerie.insertBooks(bookName,authorName, price);
            }
            catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        });


    pane.add("Delete Book", panel4);
    panel4.add(labelDelete);
    panel4.add(firstDelete);
    panel4.add(buttonDelete);
    buttonDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String bookName = firstDelete.getText();
            try {
                BookQuerie.deleteBooks(bookName);
            }
            catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        });

    add(pane);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    guiBook app = new guiBook();
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    app.setSize(1000,400);
    app.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

And Finally: the BookQuerie class:

```
 package bookDatabase;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class BookQuerie {
private static PreparedStatement selectAll;
private static PreparedStatement updateBook;
private static PreparedStatement insertBook;
private static PreparedStatement deleteBook;
private Connection connect;
private String bookName;
private static String authorName;
private static String price;
Book boooks = new Book(bookName, authorName, price);


public BookQuerie(String bookName, String authorName, String price) {
    try{
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookshop", "root", "");
        selectAll = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BOOK");
        updateBook = connect.prepareStatement("UPDATE book SET price =  ? WHERE bookName = ?");
        insertBook = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO book VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        deleteBook= connect.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM book WHERE bookName = ? ");
    }
    catch
        (SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static  String selectAll(String bookName, String authorName, String price) throws SQLException{
    ResultSet rs = selectAll.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        rs.getString ("bookName");
        rs.getString ("authorName");
        rs.getString ("price");
    }
    return selectAll(bookName, authorName, price);
}

public static int updateBooks(String bookName, String price) throws SQLException{
    updateBook.setString(1, bookName );
    updateBook.setString(2, price);
    int i = updateBook.executeUpdate();
    if(i>0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Is Saved!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is Not Saved! :( " );
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return updateBooks(bookName, price);
}

public static int insertBooks(String bookName, String authorName, String price) throws SQLException{
    insertBook.setString(1, bookName);
    insertBook.setString(2,authorName);
    insertBook.setString(3, price);
    int i = insertBook.executeUpdate();
    if(i>0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Is Saved!!");
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is Not Saved! :( " );
    }
    return insertBooks(bookName, authorName, price );
}

public static int deleteBooks (String bookName) throws SQLException{
    deleteBook.setString(1, bookName);
    return deleteBook.executeUpdate();
}


}
```

Comment: Have you tried to prepare your statement inside your corresponding method rather than declared it at the beginning? Have you tried to manually insert using a SQL GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should make the variables in the 'Book' class private. Encapsulation is a key OOP concept.

You could try naming the database columns explicitly in your insert statement too e.g.:

String query = " insert into users **(first_name, last_name, date_created, is_admin, num_points)** values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

Secondly in the guiBook (should be GuiBook or GUIBook class names should start with a capital letter) i would make use of the Book class you created.
 Create a book object from the values you get from the text fields and pass it to your 'insert' method.

```
 insertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String bookName = firstInsert.getText();
            String authorName = secondInsert.getText();
            String price = thirdInsert.getText();
            Book book = new Book(bookName,authorName, price):
            try {
                BookQuerie.insertBooks(book);
            }
            catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        });
```

Finally i would recommend changing the BookQuerie (Query) class to not create all of the prepared statements in the constructor. Instead create an individual method for each Database action you want to accomplish e.g.:

```
   public static boolean insertBook(Book book) throws SQLException{
PreparedStatement insertBook = null;
    try(Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookshop", "root", "");){

         insertBook = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO book (NAME, AUTHOR, PRICE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");


        insertBook.setString(1, book.getName());
        insertBook.setString(2,book.getAuthorName());
        insertBook.setString(3, book.getPrice());
        int i = insertBook.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Is Saved!!");
    return true;
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is Not Saved! :( " );
return false;
        }
     catch
            (SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
finally{
             insertBook.close();
             }
    }
```

Note: creating the connection inside the try(Connection conn){} is called 'try with resources' it is available from java 7 onward and will close the connection automatically at the end.

**EDIT**

One thing i never mentioned was your methods returning themselves e.g.

```
public static List<Book> selectAll() throws SQLException {
        **return selectAll();**
    }
```

This is called 'Recursion' and can lead to problems. In your code it shouldn't be there anyway.

With regards to your selectAll() method you are selecting multiple records from the DB so these will need to be stored in a list of some sort. e.g:

```
public static List<Book> selectAll() throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        // THE LIST OF BOOKS YOU WILL RETURN
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT NAME, AUTHOR, PRICE FROM BOOK";

        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookshop", "root", "");){

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                String name = rs.getString ("NAME");
                String author = rs.getString ("AUTHOR");
                String price = rs.getString ("PRICE");
                // CREATE NEW BOOK WITH EACH ROW FROM RESULTSET
                Book book = new Book( name, author, price);
                // ADD BOOK TO THE LIST
                books.add(book);
            }
        }
        finally{
            ps.close();
            rs.close();
        }
        // RETURN LIST OF ALL BOOKS
        return books;
    }
```

Then in your GuiBook class you can create another method which uses the selectAll() method to populate your Jpanel for example:

```
private void populateJPanel(){
        // GET LIST OF ALL BOOKS (selectAll() throws sql exception so we handle it here.)
        List<Book> books = null;
        try {
            books = BookQuery.selectAll();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
// LOOP THROUGH BOOK LIST
            for (Book book : books) {
                String name = book.getName();
                String author = book.getAuthor();
                String price =  book.getPrice();

                // NOW USE THESE VALUES HOWEVER YOU PLEASE ON YOUR JPANEL
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks badgerboy86! This has worked and helped alot ! I appreciate the help. Cheers!

Comment: badgerboy86 , Im still struggling to print out the select all query onto my gui class. I am trying to print it out onto a JTable but nothing i seem to do works. Any advice on how to do this? I have also upvoted for you but as my REP is under 15 , it is not shown publicly. I also marked as correct answer. cheers.